# SQL readmits in 30 day partitions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to group patient readmissions that occur within separate 30 day windows (SQL Server 2008).
After multiple attempts at recursive CTE's, I'm just going in circles.
All help is greatly appreciated.

Problem:

If a patient is admitted within 30 days of the first discharge, count all those admissions in the first period (in the example below, the second admit date of 7/7/2011 is within the 7/20/2011 window).

The first admit immediately after the above 30 day  period should be treated as a new 30 day window and any admits within 30 days of its discharge become part of group 2, etc.

So, record 3 is the start of a new 30 day window, even though this admit is within 30 days of the discharge of the prior record (admit on 8/5/2011 is before 8/26/2011, but 8/5/2011 is greater than the 7/20/2011 terminus that started the first 30 day window).

Record 4 was admitted prior to 8/31/2011, therefore it should be included in group 2.

Record 5 stands alone because it was admitted more than 30 days after the 8/31/2011 date that ended group 2.

The desired output for the example recordset is the sum of charges for each 30 day start point.

Desired result:

```
MRN   Admit      TotalCharge
555   6/14/2011  $25
555   7/30/2011  $39
555   11/3/2011  $10
```

Example recordset:

```
Acct MRN    Admit       Disc        Disch+30    Charge
590  555    6/14/2011   6/20/2011   7/20/2011   15
938  555    7/7/2011    7/27/2011   8/26/2011   10
1011 555    7/30/2011   8/1/2011    8/31/2011    9
1089 555    8/5/2011    9/14/2011   10/14/2011  30
3011 555    11/3/2011   11/23/2011  12/23/2011  10
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I see what you're saying. Let's clean this up then.

Comment: Aaron, "Disch+30" is simply an example of end of the 30 day range. I was hoping it would make it easier to follow my question.(yes, dateadd+30).

Comment: @marceln you may be right, I futzed with this for a while, but resigned to using a #temp table rather than a set-based solution. If you know exactly how you would do this in CLR, by all means, post an answer. Would be interesting to profile the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I may have been a bit ambitious insisting that this could be done with a single-pass, set-based query. This comes pretty close, but still dumps results to a #temp table in order to support quasi-parallel updates (one "thread" per MRN value, rather than a cursor that plows through one MRN at a time).

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Acct INT, MRN INT, Admit DATE, Disc DATE, Charge INT);

INSERT @t VALUES
(590 , 555, '20110614','20110620',15), 
(938 , 555, '20110707','20110727',10),
(1011, 555, '20110730','20110801', 9),
(1089, 555, '20110805','20110914',30),
(3011, 555, '20111103','20111123',10);

SELECT MRN, [group] = CONVERT(INT, NULL), Admit, Disc, Charge, 
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MRN ORDER BY Admit),
  da = DATEADD(DAY, 30, Disc)
  INTO #x FROM @t; -- add a WHERE clause if examining a set in a bigger table

DECLARE @rn INT = 0;

WHILE @rn IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT @rn = MIN(rn) FROM #x WHERE [group] IS NULL;

  UPDATE agg SET [group] = @rn
    FROM #x AS agg
    INNER JOIN #x AS src
    ON agg.MRN = src.MRN
    AND agg.Admit <= src.da
    AND agg.[group] IS NULL
    AND src.rn = @rn;
END
GO
SELECT MRN, Admit = MIN(Admit), TotalCharge = SUM(Charge)
  FROM #x GROUP BY MRN, [group];
GO
DROP TABLE #x;
```

Results:

```
MRN  Admit       TotalCharge
---  ----------  -----------
555  2011-06-14  25
555  2011-07-30  39
555  2011-11-03  10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was switching over to a cursor attempt, but this is preferable and I can tweak it to fit my final need (adding some diagnosis info, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Perform a self-join of the date table to itself, to identify all admissions NOT preceded by another admission within 30 days; call that relation T1 and make it a sub-query of the main query.

Now join T1 to data again to pick up all secondary admissions from data for each row in T1.

I may have time to look at this again later tonight.